# Como associar valores(preço) passados através do mysqli_fetch_array a um produto?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como associar alguns valores que eu tenho armazenado em um *array* à um produto em específico, segue abaixo meu código:

```php
<?php while ($consulta = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <!--laço para dispor produtos no card-->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        </br>
        <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap"><?php echo "<img src='../image/" . $consulta['image'] . "' />" ?></div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
                <h4 class="title"><?php echo $consulta['nome'] ?></h4>
                <p class="desc"><?php echo utf8_encode($consulta["observacao"]) ?></p>
            </figcaption>

            <div class="bottom-wrap">

                <?php $valor = $consulta["valor"] ?>
                <?php if ($saldo >= $consulta["valor"]) { ?>
                    <!--Condicional para realizar pedido-->

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalProduto">
                        Solicitar
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modalProduto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Confirmação de compra</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body modalzin">
                                    <img src="../src/img/customer-service.png" alt="customer-service">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="adq" class="btn btn-success conf">Confirmar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" disabled>
                        Saldo insuficiente
                    </button>
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="price-wrap h5">
                    <span class="price-new" id="price-new"><?php echo $consulta["valor"] ?></span>
                </div> <!-- price-wrap.// -->

            </div> <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
        </figure>
    </div> <!-- col // -->
<?php } ?><!--laço para dispor produtos no card.//-->
```

No código acima tem um `$consulta['valor']` que armazena os valores que eu tenho no *DB*, todo esse laço dispõe cada produto em um *card*, a pergunta é:

Como eu posso fazer pra que quando o cliente clicar no botão `solicitar`, ele pega apenas o valor que esta naquele *card* especifico e não o vetor `$consulta['valor'] inteiro`?

Comment: creio que uma forma seria, jogar o valor na propriedade "value" de um input e depois pegar ela via POST quando clicar no submit

Comment: vc pode utilizar um foreach do array de valores para associar ao registro desejado;

Comment: galera consegui resolver essa questão, coloquei um atributo `data-valor="<?= $consulta['valor'] ?>"` no botão solicitar e usei uma função jquery `    `<script>
        $(".pegarValor").on('click', function() {
            let elemento;
            elemento = $(this).data('valor');
            console.log(elemento);
        });
    </script>`

Comment: Valeu pelas sugestões :)